# rTorrent - Different default save directories for different autolaunch directories

Tags: automation, home-server, rtorrent

I've been using rTorrent on my home-server for a while and I'd like to explore some of the cooler features of it. One thing I've had going for a while is an autolaunch directory and a default save directory.

What I'd like to do is set up a autolaunch directory for each linux distribution I seed so that I can drop new image torrents into the related watch directory and have them auto start. The caveat is that I'd like to maintain a very specific file structure on the server, where each distro is saved under a different path.

Is there a way (possibly via the `schedule=` directive) to have multiple auto-launch directories that will each save to a different default save directory?

Note: I already have multiple rTorrent instances for various reasons, so I'd rather not have to start new instances for each distro.

Relevant parts of .DistroMirrors.rtorrent.rc:

```
#Default Save Directory
directory = /torrent/DISTRO/iso
#Auto-Launch Directory
schedule = watch_directory,5,5,load=/torrent/DISTRO/auto/*.torrent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, then yes, you can do this.  You can have multiple watch directories that save to different directories.

note: Your version of rtorrent must be 0.7.7+

```
schedule = tied_directory,10,10,start_tied=
schedule = untied_directory,10,10,close_untied=
schedule = watch_directory_1,10,10,"load_start=~/Download/watch_stuff_1/*.torrent,d.set_directory=~/Download/stuff_1/"
schedule = watch_directory_2,10,10,"load_start=~/Download/watch_stuff_2/*.torrent,d.set_directory=~/Download/stuff_2/"
```

This is all from there common usage section of there [Wiki](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentCommonTasks#Watchadirectoryfortorrents).
I see most people mess this up by using 'watch_directory' multiple times, which is just writing over the previous write directory statement.  Make sure they are each named differently.

Comment: Is there a single list with all the options for schedule? I can find references here and there but I can't seem to locate a list that says: Here is all the options and here is all the specifications for what they do.

Comment: You can help to build one: http://wiki.rtorrent.org/XmlRpcReference